# Echo Message to JSF 2.0 Page

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm new to JSF 2.0 and am trying to output a message to my page.  I want to have a form that accepts some input, does some processing, and displays some output.  Seems pretty simple right?  However, I don't want to define a property in my backing bean to display the output via:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.property}" />
```

That approach seems very messy to me; I would need a member variable for every status message I want to display.  I also don't want to bind the output display to a form variable as in:

```
<h:inputText id="someId" />
<h:message for="someId" />
```

because there is no corresponding form variable for my status result.  Setting a message and using the global messages:

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

doesn't work well either because I might need to update multiple elements on the page (not lump all my status messages into the same div).

Coming from Spring MVC, one can set arbitrary properties on the ModelAndView object that is passed to the View, and then access those properties from within the view.  Is there a corresponding way of doing this in JSF?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make arbitrary variables easily available to the view, you could define a Map in e.g. request scope by putting the following in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <description>Request scoped map for general usage</description>
    <managed-bean-name>map</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

You can inject this map in your backing bean, or programmatically request it, and then put something in it. E.g.:

```
@ManagedBean
public class GeneralMapBacking {

    @ManagedProperty("#{map}")
    private Map<Object, Object> map;

    public void onPreRenderView() {
        map.put("foo", "bar");
    }

    public void setMap(Map<Object, Object> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }  
}
```

You can reference this map via EL on your Facelet, e.g.:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>
    <h:body>   
        <f:event listener="#{generalMapBacking.onPreRenderView}" type="preRenderView" />

        #{map.foo}       
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. I am also unfamiliar with Spring MVC and that example passed me by I must say.

However I think it basically sounds like you want to either construct the output serverside or use another component.

For example use a single `<h:outputText>`and use it with a getter that returns concatenated data.

Or perhaps you should use a `<h:dataTable>` to display your data?

Or maybe you want to output using some other component. It sounds like you just want a box with text and for that I myself would use the concatenated outputText.

For good looking output you might want to look into primefaces, richfaces or icefaces. I prefer primefaces myself and maybe this would look nice:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dataListUnordered.jsf

Comment: yea, i don't want to bind a getter to an output text.  then i am going to have a getter for every UI field i want to set basically.